# How to create page turn effect when page loading in Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add page turn effect (like book reading) to the iframe, at the time of loading some dynamic content in it. How can I achieve it? Please help me.

Link: http://www.turnjs.com/

Comment: <a href="default.html"  target="myIframe" > </a> <a href="two.html"  target="myIframe" > </a> <iframe src="" id="myIframe" name="myIframe" style="border: #69C;width:100%;height:80%;">
        </iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#myIframe").turn({
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                autoCenter: true
            });
        </script> @SibeeshVenu

Comment: I use turn.js code. [link](http://www.turnjs.com/)

Comment: if you have an answer post an answer, dont put blocks of code in a comment

Comment: @nick, some tips for you to make the SO-experience best possible: Here in StackOverflow (SO) you ought to add the code you have tried that didn't work. If you want people her to make an effort to solve your problem, we need to see that you have actually tried to solve the issue yourself. You can update your question with the code you have tried. Also add a link to the turn.js page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want:

1) the iframe to be **one page inside the book?**

Or

2) the iframe **be a book with many pages?**

If the first, you probably can add the iframe inside a DIV (page).

Code fetched from http://www.turnjs.com, I just added the iframe example.

```
<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1 Here you can load the iframe <iframe src="..."> </div>
    <div> Page 2 Here you can load another iframe <iframe src="..."></div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

If the last you need to load the turn.js inside the iframe (You must be able to control the iframe's content.)

Then this must be inside the iframe:

```
<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1, load content with AJAX if dynamic</div>
    <div> Page 2, load content with AJAX if dynamic </div>
    <div> Page 3, etc </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

You can load the content inside the DIVs ("pages") using AJAX/ Javascript.